# Undefined symbols for architecture armv

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, arm7

I'm having an issue with my app. I am receiving 7 Apple Mach-O Linker errors. Here are the errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_SideSwipeTableViewController.sideSwipeCell", referenced from:
  -[ViewController touchUpInsideAction:] in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SideSwipeTableViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SideSwipeTableViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_SideSwipeTableViewController.tableView", referenced from:
  -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  -[ViewController touchUpInsideAction:] in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SideSwipeTableViewCell", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_SideSwipeTableViewController.sideSwipeView", referenced from:
  -[ViewController setupSideSwipeView] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This has been driving me nuts and I would like to get this fixed. I have been looking though Google, Bing, and StackOverflow and while I did find some "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" issues, none of them have helped me.

I am using Xcode 4.3.1. I am running OS X Lion 10.7.3. I am testing the app using an iPhone running iOS 5.1.

Could anyone please help me? I would appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These linker errors mean that classes called SideSwipeTableViewController and SideSwipeTableViewCell weren't compiled, but are used elsewhere in your code. If these aren't classes that are part of a static library, make sure they're in your project's Compile Sources build phase. If they are part of a static library, it means the version of the library you're linking against was probably built for a different architecture.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I've built my library for an aggregate of targets, with build-active-arch-only = NO.  (Maybe I've set this up incorrectly, I'm new to this.)  Yet I'm still getting the error.  As far as I can tell, I've done all the correct steps.  Can you update with a bullet-list of things to check?  Thanks!